# When must I use an application server?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, ejb

I have read some posts and answers about the differences between Web Server and Application Server... Mainly, the fact that application server can serve other protocols than HTTP and provides EJB. Problem is, I have never understood what were the EJBs actually. The more I read on the subject, the less I seem to understand...

To sum up, I can't understand what EJBs bring that cannot be done another way, with simple Java classes ?

And, since I can't understand this... I can't understand when an application server is necessary. When is Apache Tomcat (for instance) not enough for my needs ? What would force me to use an application server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can actually use tomcat for Java EE development, but you will need to carry a lot of libraries (.jar) to use it, also, depending of the implementation of the specs (e.g: redhat jpa vs oracle jpa) you could mixing some libs and end up with a hard to maintain system.

Application Server is the term that stands for a server with a highly integrated (and tested) full Java EE stack. For example according to the spec, Tomee, Wildfly and Glassfish are enough to write and run applications that uses jpa, ejb, jsf (and all the zillion of Java EE specs). Also, with a minimum of effort you can migrate between app servers (well, this is easier to say than to do).

Web Server (á la tomcat) is more servlet oriented, you only have a minimum of specs running and because of that, you will need to add the interfaces and the implementations on your own (yeah, that zillion of .jars, belive me, you dont want this for a project). I will recommend tomcat for websites not depending on java ee infrastructure, unless!, that you like to work with Spring (some jars to add but is easier and well integrated).

Keep the things simple and use an App Server if you need a Java EE app, by the other hand, if you are a Spring devoted, use Tomcat+Spring, but, for the love of god, not mix both at the same time for the same app.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use tomcat you can use springframefork. As says spring reference only one thing cannot be make using spring, but can be make using EJB. And it is two fase distributed transactions between different application servers throw remote call.